# How to implementing O(1) lookup of item state belonging to container

Tags: c#, containers

I have a container that holds a lot (millions) of objects and must maintain a validated state for each item, eg:

```
class MyContainer<T>
{
    bool IsValidated(T t);
}
```

Whether an item is validated is entirely a concept of the container. Items have no such concept. So how to implement the Validated state of items in this situation? I'll explain the problem with two solutions I thought of:

Solution 1) Add a Validated property to the item itself, by forcing items added to the collection to inherit from a base class:

```
class MyContainer<T> where T : BaseItem
{
    bool IsValidated(T t)
    {
        return t.IsValidated;
    }
}

class BaseItem
{
    bool IsValidated;
}
```

But this seems wrong. Whether an item is validated or not is a concern of the container. The item shouldn't have any concept of what "validated" means. But on the other-hand this is the only solution I can think of that given an Item, allows its validation state to be looked up in O(1).

Solution 2) Maintain a dictionary in the container to associate Items with validation state:

```
class MyContainer<T>
{
    Dictionary<T, bool> isValidated;

    bool IsValidated(T t)
    {
        return isValidated[t];
    }
}
```

This solves the "wrongness" of the first solution. It removes all knowledge of validation from the Item and also doesn't require items to inherit a base class. But on the bad side the lookup to determine an Item's validation state is now O(log n).

What I cannot get over is how the worst solution in terms of design (#1) is better in terms of lookup performance. Nothing I can think of except the bad design of solution #1 can produce O(1) lookup.

Is there a well designed solution for O(1) or should I just settle on O(log n) lookup?

Comment: Couldn't you have isValidated as a property of the container, and then update it as new items are added/removed?

Comment: the container must maintain a separate IsValidated state for each item

Comment: Well, actually Dictionary lookup is asymptotically `O(1)` ... even if is surely slower than the first case. However, I hardly think this could be the bottleneck...

Comment: Dictionary lookup of O(1)?? I thought it was O(log n) am I wrong?

Comment: It's *very close* to O(1)

Comment: SortedList/SortedDictionary are implemented using sorted list and red-black trees respectively so they have lookup complexity `O(log n)`. Dictionary is implemented as an hash-table and has `O(1)` lookup complexity...

Comment: @WeylandYutani: [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx): "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class is implemented as a hash table"

Comment: If your container needs a IsValidated per item, then perhaps a decorator approach might be cleanest?

Comment: sorry guys i screwed up on this one. I was so sure it was log n that i didn't bother to check....*embarrassed face*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave wrote, the Dictionary's complexity is close to O(1)

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1),
>   because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash
>   table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: I’m not sure what “close to O(1)” means. Shame on MSDN for employing such imprecise and misleading language.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I slightly disagree, no one can guarantee true O(1) in a multithreaded environment anyway so it's always almost O(1).

Comment: That’s not how O(1) works – at least usually it denotes performance on an idealised processor (consequently in a single thread). Furthermore, there simply are conventions to follow if you want to be understood. MSDN simply ignores these conventions here. And saying “it’s always almost O(1)” is a useless statement, don’t you agree? If it’s always that, then why talk about it? To be exact: Amortised hash table retrieval is either exactly O(1) or it’s O(n)/a, depending on the load factor. It’s never “close to O(1)”.

Comment: I think it has to be constant in terms of cycles which is independent from the technical architecture. I agree 'almost' here doesn't make the answer very professional...